# Center text using Synchfusion's SfDataGrid for UWP with dynamic columns

Tags: uwp, datagrid, syncfusion

I am trying to center the text in the cells for a SfDataGrid in UWP. The columns are bound during runtime so I can not set a cell style on column elements.

The xaml for the grid looks like this:

```
                  <grid:SfDataGrid Name="GridData"
                                     AlternatingRowStyle="{StaticResource mainTableRowStyle}"
                                     RowStyle="{StaticResource mainTableRowStyle}"
                                     HeaderStyle="{StaticResource headerStyle}"
                                     Foreground="WhiteSmoke"
                                     framework:FocusExtension.IsFocused="{Binding Focused}"
                                     AllowSelectionOnPointerPressed="True"
                                     Grid.Row="0"
                                     Columns="{Binding SfGridColumns, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                     AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                                     IsDynamicItemsSource="True"
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=dataPager,Path=PagedSource}"
                                     ColumnSizer="Star"
                                     AllowSorting="False"
                                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGridItem, Mode =TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Holding">
                                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding HoldCommand}" />
                            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </grid:SfDataGrid>
```

I have tried to add a style to the cells in order to align the text:

```
    <Style x:Key="cellStyle" TargetType="grid:GridCell">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    </Style>
   <!-- CellStyle="{StaticResource cellStyle}" -->
```

But that doesn't help because it centers the entire cell and the inner borders of the grid are disrupted. (looks something like the below picture)

[image]

I want just the text inside the cell to be aligned. (also tried the HorizontalContentAlignment center, it didn't do anything)

Finally, I have tried to rewrite the template of the cell. The SfDataGrid does not have a CellTemplate property, but it has a GridCellTemplateSelector property. So, I have created a template like this:

```
    <framework:GridCellTemplateSelector x:Key="templateSelector"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CellTemplate1">
        <TextBlock Foreground="DarkBlue" Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </DataTemplate> <!-- and added CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}" to the grid -->

public class GridCellTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            return Application.Current.Resources["CellTemplate1"] as DataTemplate;
        }
    }
```

This one doesn't work also because it seems the method in GridCellTemplateSelector is not hit. I am thinking if I could make the CellTemplateSelector to work I could achieve my objective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'GridCellTemplateSelector' is not for your scenario. The sfDataGrid has 'CellTemplate', it's available for the columns.

I made a code sample for your reference:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <syncfusion:SfDataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
                           ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}">
    </syncfusion:SfDataGrid>
</Grid>
```

```cs
public class OrderInfo
{
    int orderID;
    string customerId;
    string customerName;

    public int OrderID
    {
        get { return orderID; }
        set { orderID = value; }
    }

    public string CustomerID
    {
        get { return customerId; }
        set { customerId = value; }
    }

    public string CustomerName
    {
        get { return customerName; }
        set { customerName = value; }
    }



    public OrderInfo(int orderId, string customerName, string customerId)
    {
        this.OrderID = orderId;
        this.CustomerName = customerName;
        this.CustomerID = customerId;
    }
}
```

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private ObservableCollection<OrderInfo> _orders;

    public ObservableCollection<OrderInfo> Orders
    {
        get { return _orders; }
        set { _orders = value; }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        _orders = new ObservableCollection<OrderInfo>();
        this.GenerateOrders();
        this.DataContext = this;
        Type mytype = Orders.FirstOrDefault().GetType();
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in mytype.GetProperties())
        {
            dataGrid.Columns.Add(new GridTextColumn() { MappingName = pi.Name, TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, HeaderText = pi.Name });
        }
    }

    private void GenerateOrders()
    {
        _orders.Add(new OrderInfo(1001, "Maria Anders",  "ALFKI"));
        _orders.Add(new OrderInfo(1002, "Ana Trujillo",  "ANATR"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. But, as I have described in the question, the columns are dynamic and bound during runtime which is why I couldn't use something similar with this example. This is a generic grid that can have one, two, or more columns depending on the data. I want a way to align center all the contents in all columns.

Comment: Inspired by your response I have managed to solve it by setting the TextAlignment property from code when I was creating the columns. can you please update your response with something like    {for (var i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
                SfGridColumns.Add(new GridTextColumn
                    {
                        MappingName = "Collection[" + i + "].DisplayValue",
                        TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                        HeaderText = Headers[i].Name
                    }
                );}          In order to mark it as the answer?

Comment: @Cosmin I also find this strange behavior. If I set 'TextAlignment' in XAML style, it will be override. I've updated my reply.